# Confirm email in Magento using the Web-forms

Tags: magento

I am using an extension in Magento called web-forms to create all the forms on my website. What I need to do is add the email verification fields (user must enter email twice. Both emails must match) How can I do this? I looked thru the extension but did not see a way to do it.

It looks like the web-forms is using prototype.js for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it in case someone in the future has the same problem and in using the web-forms extension here is how you do it.

1. Assign css class thru the back end in magento->web-forms-(your form name)->the confirm email field(which you should create if you don't have it all ready)design tab->CSS classes for the Input element(put your class name here and remember it you are going to use it later)
2. Next open up in your root directory of the magento installation the validation.js file. Which is located in js/prototype/
3. Open the file and paste the code below after the validate-email

```html
['[your class name]', 'Please make sure your emails match.', function(v)
{
var conf = $$('.[your class name]')[0];
var pass = false;
if ($('email')) {
pass = $('email');
}
var emailElements = $$('.validate-email');
for (var i = 0; i < emailElements.size(); i++) {
var emailElement = emailElements[i];
if (emailElement.up('form').id == conf.up('form').id) {
pass = emailElement;
}
}
if ($$('.[your class name]').size()) {
pass = $$('.validate-email')[0];
}
return (pass.value == conf.value);
}],
```

4. save it and upload it

   Hope that helps somebody you has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Above code is not working correctly following part is creating issue

```
if ($$('.[your class name]').size()) {
 pass = $$('.validate-email')[0];
}
```

at my end following code is working

```
if ($$('.validate-admin-email').size()) {
pass = $$('.validate-admin-email')[0];
}
```

so the complete working code can be:

```
['validate-cemail', 'Please make sure your emails match.', function(v) {
var conf = $$('.validate-cemail')[0];
var pass = false;
if ($('email')) {
pass = $('email');
}
var emailElements = $$('.validate-email');
for (var i = 0; i < emailElements.size(); i++) {
var emailElement = emailElements[i];
if (emailElement.up('form').id == conf.up('form').id) {
pass = emailElement;
}
}
if ($$('.validate-admin-email').size()) {
pass = $$('.validate-admin-email')[0];
}
return (pass.value == conf.value);
}],
```

.validate-cemail is your defined class in template.
like:

```
<input type="text" name="email-confirm" id="email-confirm" class="input-text required-entry validate-cemail"/>
```